# FFmpeg constant framerate to variable

Tags: video, ffmpeg, framerate

When recording gameplay with constant 60fps, it records at 60 fps even if the gameplay is ~30 fps or lower.

Is there any way to transcode the 60fps video from constant to variable FPS, so it uses timestamps not FPS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf mpdecimate -vsync vfr out.mp4
```

The `mpdecimate` filter removes duplicate frames, if present, in the recording. The `vsync vfr` prevents FFmpeg from duplicating frames to match the stored framerate.

Comment: You're a magician

Comment: Thanks a lot! This achieved the higher level goal to [significantly reduce file size while maintaining the same quality in videos like screen recordings](https://superuser.com/a/1792778/40829) which have some dynamic scenes which should be kept at max FPS but also some scenes where a still image (I-frame) lasts e.g. 10 seconds (= 1/10 = 0.1 FPS).